# Nant Script Task using Cruise Control

Tags: nant

im using script task  in nant Script, in script task i have written C# code in which i'm trying to write to console as below

console.writeline("Hello");

and also i have a method and its return type.

Actually i'm calling this Nant script from  Cruise Control web dashboard.

Now my question is i can see only the return type of method in nant ouptut on Cruise Control Web Dash Board but i dont see console.writeline("Hello") message, so how can i get console message also on cruise control dashboard under nant Output? Is there any way to show console messages on cruise control Web dash Board

,

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the NAnt Log methods to write your output, e.g.

```
<script language="C#">
  <code>
    <![CDATA[
      public static void ScriptMain(Project project) 
      {
        // ...
        project.Log(Level.Info, "Moving directory {0} to {1}", source, destination);
      }
    ]]>
  </code>
</script>
```